# Where is the ARP source code in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, protocols

I want to know how Linux implements its ARP, and I tried to find the source code of ARP in the Linux kernel source code tree, but I could not find it. Could you please tell me where I can find it?

Answer (score 10):

It's under [net/ipv4/arp.c](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.2.6/net/ipv4/arp.c).